# Does a probability distribution exist given a finite number of moments?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-problem

Given a finite set of moments $(m_n)$ for $n\in V \subset \mathbb Z^+$, is there a way to determine that there exists a probability distribution $d\mu(x)$ such that $m_n = \int x^n d\mu(x)$ for $n\in V$? (Assuming we always have $m_0 = 1$.)

In particular, can this question be answered without constructing all possible $(\tilde m_n)_{n\in \mathbb Z^+}$ such that $\tilde m_n = m_n$  for $n\in V$? If I have all moments, then a positive semidefinite matrix given by the elements $H_{i,j} = \tilde m_{i+j}$ implies I can construct such a probability distribution, but is there a way to see that this matrix can be made positive semidefinite without testing all ways to construct $\tilde m_n$?

Comment: I think you can extract an answer from classical results about orthogonal polynomials but I am too lazy to verify the details. What you want is to compute the sequences $a_i, b_i$ from this blog post and check that all the $b_i$ are nonnegative, then (I think) extend the sequences by setting all subsequent values to zero: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/moments-hankel-determinants-orthogonal-polynomials-motzkin-paths-and-continued-fractions/

Comment: Not necessarily the first $n$ moments?

Comment: @KeithMcClary Not necessarily, but the restriction to that case could still be quite helpful.

Comment: Akhiezer's "The Classical Moment Problem", p. 30 discusses the "truncated moment problem", but assumes the existence of of a "positive sequence" of moments ($0, ... \infty$).

Comment: Is your question equivalent to: "Given a finite set of real numbers $(r_n)$ for $n\in V \subset \mathbb Z^+$, is there a way to determine that there exists a 'positive sequence' ${m_n}$ such that $m_n = r_n$ for $n\in V$?"? If so, you could tag it [linear-algebra] and attract those experts (with their embarrassing 2x2 counterexamples, etc.).

Comment: Is this answer can be helpful ?? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286926/truncated-sieltjes-r-atomic-moment-problem